# JavaFX 2 slider labelFormatter not being used

Tags: java, javafx-2

I have the following code that does not label the slider "foo50", etc... as one would expect with the `setLabelFormatter` call, but instead seems to have no effect (the slider is labelled 50, 100, etc and the println's dont run). Is there something I am missing? Is this not implemented in the default 2.2 Skin? Using Oracle Java 7

```
package javafxbugtest;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.*;
import javafx.scene.control.*;
import javafx.stage.*;
import javafx.util.StringConverter;

public class JavaFXBugTest extends Application
{
    @Override
    public void start(final Stage primaryStage)
    {
        Slider cp = new Slider();
        cp.setLabelFormatter(new StringConverter<Double>() {

            @Override
            public String toString(Double t)
            {
                System.out.println("nope?");
                return "foo" + t.toString();
            }

            @Override
            public Double fromString(String string)
            {
                System.out.println("hey");
                throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
            }
        });
        cp.setMax(300);
        cp.setMin(0);
        cp.setShowTickLabels(true);
        cp.setShowTickMarks(true);
        cp.setMajorTickUnit(50);
        cp.setMinorTickCount(4);
        cp.setValue(152);
        Scene scene = new Scene(cp);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Slider label formatters not working in JavaFX 2.x (Java 7) looks like a bug which has been fixed in [Java 8](http://jdk8.java.net/download.html):

[RT-18448 [Slider] label formatter is not applicable.](https://javafx-jira.kenai.com/browse/RT-18448)